# Log my external IP address using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've been learning NodeJS recently, and have a small program to get the external IP address on my home network from fugal.net, compare it to the previous IP address, and if there is a change update the stored version, and send an email with the new IP.

I'm running node 0.11.12 on a Raspberry Pi, and storing on mongodb 2.1.1. I would appreciate any recommendations on how to improve it.

```
var http = require('http');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create reusable transporter object using SMTP transport
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'mygmail@gmail.com',
        pass: 'mypassword'
    }
});

var config = {
    hostname: 'fugal.net',
    path: '/ip.cgi',
    agent: false
};

http.request(config, function(res) {

    if(res.statusCode != 200) {
        throw new Error('non-OK status: ' + res.statusCode);
    }
    res.setEncoding('utf-8');
    var ipAddress = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {    ipAddress += chunk; });
    res.on('end', function() {  
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {

            var collection = db.collection('test');
            collection.findOne({}, function(err, item) {

                var changeNeeded = false;
                if(item.ipAddress != ipAddress) {

                    changeNeeded = true;
                    db.collection('test').update({_id: item._id}, {$set: {ipAddress: ipAddress}}, {w:1}, function(err) {
                        if(err) throw err;
                        db.close();
                    });
                    sendMail(ipAddress);

                }
                if(!changeNeeded)
                    db.close();

            });

        });

    });

}).on('error', function(err) {
    throw err;
}).end();

function sendMail(ipAddress) {

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'mygmail@gmail.com', // sender address
        to: 'mygmail@gmail.com',   // list of receivers
        subject: 'IP Address Changed',  // Subject line
        text: 'New IP Address: ' + ipAddress       // html body
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });

}
```

The big stumbling block for me was where to put the call to "db.close()" because of JavaScript's asynchronous nature.

The code to get the IP address was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273128/how-to-get-my-external-ip-address-with-node-js). The nodemail code is straight from the usage example on http://www.nodemailer.com.